# Binding DataTemplate's datacontext property to a usercontrol dependency property

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In a UWP application, i have a Listview with a datatemplate. The ListView is binded via ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection of my model.

```
<ListView SelectionMode="None"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MydataTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Meals, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Meals is the ObservableCollection of model Meal :

```
public class Meal
{
    public string restaurantId { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Inside ListView DataTemplate, i have a User Control (each element of the ListView have this User control). I want to bind the current meal quantity (Quantity property) to a dependency proeprty of the User control :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="mydataTemplate">
    ...
    <ccontrol:MyUC Value="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2" />
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

With User control DP :

```
public sealed partial class MyUC : UserControl
{
    public MyUC()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(ResaNumUpDown), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

But at runtime i have a binding expression error :

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Quantity' property not found on 'Project.MyUC'

It search on UserControl, but i want to search Quantity property in DataTemplate data context.

I red [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332815/binding-a-usercontrol-dp-from-datatemplate-uwp) who doesn't help me a lot.

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not explicitly set a UserControl's `DataContext`, like you do in the `MyUC` constructor. Doing so prevents inheriting the DataContext from the parent control of the UserControl.

```
public MyUC()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    // this.DataContext = this; // remove this line
}
```

A Binding like

```
<ccontrol:MyUC Value="{Binding Quantity}" />
```

expects a property `Quantity` in the current (inherited) DataContext, which here is the current element in the `ItemsSource` collection of the ListView. This won't work when you've explicitly set the `DataContext`.

In the UserControl's XAML, write a Bindings such that it takes the UserControl as its source by specifying the Binding's `ElementName` property:

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="self">
   ...
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=self}" />
   ...
</UserControl>
```